# React Native: Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, native-base

I am trying to make an onPress function such that when the menu icon is clicked, my drawer navigation will open. However, I am getting this error: Unhandled JS Exception: Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined.

Here's my code for HeaderComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Header, Left, Icon, Body, Title, Right } from 'native-base';

const HeaderComponent = (props) => {
const { menuIconStyle } = styles;

return (
    <Header>
        <Left>
            <Icon
                style={menuIconStyle}
                name="menu"
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}
            />
        </Left>
        <Body>
            <Title>{props.headerText}</Title>
        </Body>
        <Right>

        </Right>
    </Header>
);
}

export default HeaderComponent;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
menuIconStyle: {
    paddingLeft: 15,
},
});
```

Would appreciate a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Seem like the parameter is undefined. How do you render this component?

Comment: @nikosfotiadis I imported it into HomeScreen.js and rendered it there like this <HeaderComponent headerText={'Home'} />

Comment: @user7381027 I assume `HomeScreen` has `navigation` in props. If that is the case, you need to pass `navigation` to HeaderComponent too: `<HeaderComponent headerText={"Home"} navigation={this.props.navigation} />`

Comment: @blaz I see. It's working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should pass navigation props from parent to child,like this:

`<HeaderComponent navigation={this.props.navigation} />`

then you can use navigation in your child component

Answer (score 0):

Your component is not a ES6 class but a function. So, you cannot use `this.props` because it doesn't exist.

`onPress={() => props.navigation.openDrawer()}`

use this instead.